# Database :how to separate sql queries coming from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL query which uses UNION in order to obtain data from two tables. I need a way to find out which data is coming from which table in the UI. Is there a way to insert a flag which could say about the data coming from a particular table ? I know that firing two queries may be a solution but I want to try and keep it in one query. Is there a solution ?

Comment: I have a solution, but I won't show it to you until you show us your query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'table1' AS 'table', * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2' AS 'table', * FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
  SELECT 'T1' as tbl, Field1,Field2,Field3 From TABLE1 UNION 
  SELECT 'T2' as tbl, Field1,Field2,Field3 From TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are combining data from two tables, then you should be using `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.  `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates, even if none exist.

So:

```
select t1.*, 'table1' as which
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*, 'table2'
from table2 t2;
```

The use of `*` presumes that the columns and types are identical/compatible in the two tables.